# Linux executable opening shared library through dlopen crashing on emplace_back

Tags: c++

I've created a shared library ('dylib' on OSX, 'so' on Ubuntu) and an executable that loads this library. If I simply link the shared library to the executable (link_libraries in cmake), everything works.

Now I'm not linking it, but open the library with dlopen/dlsym. On OSX that works and the executable runs smoothly, but on Linux it crashes at a particular point. Here's the valgrind trace:

```
==7253== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
 ==7253==    at 0x0: ???
==7253==    by 0x61DB539: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::thread>::construct<std::thread, ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long)::{lambda()#1}>(std::thread*, ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long)::{lambda()#1}&&) (new_allocator.h:136)
==7253==    by 0x61D7780: void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::thread> >::construct<std::thread, ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long)::{lambda()#1}>(std::allocator<std::thread>&, std::thread*, ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long)::{lambda()#1}&&) (alloc_traits.h:475)
==7253==    by 0x61D7840: void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::_M_realloc_insert<ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long)::{lambda()#1}>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::thread*, std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> > >, ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long)::{lambda()#1}&&) (vector.tcc:415)
==7253==    by 0x61D371D: void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::emplace_back<ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long)::{lambda()#1}>(ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long)::{lambda()#1}&&) (vector.tcc:105)
==7253==    by 0x61D19F5: ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long) (ThreadPool.h:38)
==7253==    by 0x112545: main (testexecutable.cpp:216)
==7253==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7253== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==7253==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x0
==7253==    at 0x0: ???
==7253==    by 0x61DB539: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::thread>::construct<std::thread, ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long)::{lambda()#1}>(std::thread*, ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long)::{lambda()#1}&&) (new_allocator.h:136)
==7253==    by 0x61D7780: void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::thread> >::construct<std::thread, ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long)::{lambda()#1}>(std::allocator<std::thread>&, std::thread*, ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long)::{lambda()#1}&&) (alloc_traits.h:475)
==7253==    by 0x61D7840: void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::_M_realloc_insert<ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long)::{lambda()#1}>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::thread*, std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> > >, ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long)::{lambda()#1}&&) (vector.tcc:415)
==7253==    by 0x61D371D: void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::emplace_back<ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long)::{lambda()#1}>(ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long)::{lambda()#1}&&) (vector.tcc:105)
==7253==    by 0x61D19F5: ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned long) (ThreadPool.h:38)
==7253==    by 0x112545: main (testexecutable.cpp:216)
```

The code is actually something like this:

```
...
// need to keep track of threads so we can join them
std::vector< std::thread > workers;
// the task queue
std::queue< std::function<void()> > tasks;
...

// the constructor just launches some amount of workers
inline ThreadPool::ThreadPool(size_t threads)
: stop(false)
{
for (size_t i = 0; i<threads; ++i)
    workers.emplace_back(
        [this]
   {
...
```

and the crash is exactly at the emplace_back call. Any ideas why this happens? GCC is 7.3.0, Ubuntu 18.04.

---

**Edit 1**

[Link to github repo with code](https://github.com/belveder79/broken)

---

**Edit 2**

Ok, so here's part of the solution. My colleague pointed out that it might be due to a placement of function pointers (lambdas) onto different stacks for the executable and the shared library, causing confusion - I could not verify that yet, but here is what I found out:

```
ldd test
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd6bdc7000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd8766de000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd876350000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd875f5f000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd876ae5000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd875bc1000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd8759a9000)
```

does not show *pthread* as required library. However the shared lib references pthread.

```
ldd liblibrary.so 
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc97b74000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007efce4d30000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007efce49a2000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007efce478a000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007efce4399000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007efce515f000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007efce3ffb000)
```

Despite it being referenced, any call to a function requiring *pthread* inside the shared library causes a crash in the application - as it seems, the *pthread* library is not loaded at all.

If I place a call to thread into main, i.e.

```
void dummyfunction() {}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   std::thread dummy(&dummyfunction);
   dummy.join();
   ...
   // dlopen/dlsym here...
   ...
   initFunction();
   ...
   // dlclose
   return 0;
}
```

*pthread* gets added to the list of libraries,

```
ldd test
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdc7bd0000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5d13777000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5d13573000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5d131e5000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5d12fcd000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5d12bdc000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5d13b9c000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5d1283e000)
```

it gets loaded and everything works also inside the shared lib.

**But why does the pthread library not get loaded from a shared library?**

Also tried using `dlopen` in the shared library on *pthread*, but that did not work.

Comment: Looks like some sort of null pointer dereference (or call to a null function pointer). For more information, post actual code.

Comment: Might be the Static Initialization Order Fiasco (postponed to `dlopen` rather than happening before `main`). Are `workers` and tasks global objects? When are they first used?

Comment: @melpomene that's the actual code...

Comment: @aschepler the workers are members of Threadpool, and that' si the first time they are used in the constructor...

Comment: @ClemensArth 1) You said it's "*something like this*", not actual code. 2) if it were actual code, it wouldn't compile (syntax error at `...`).

Comment: @melpomene I can't upload the full code, but what it does is 
`handle = dlopen("library.so"); typedef void (*initFunction_t)(); initFunction_t initFunction = (initFunction_t) dlsym(handle,"initFunction"); initFunction();`

and that one does
`ThreadPool *x = new ThreadPool(3);`

here's the link [https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool/blob/master/ThreadPool.h]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: "Questions *seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")* must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."

Comment: ok, give me a minute to create one...

Comment: @melpomene There you go:
[https://github.com/belveder79/broken]

Comment: @ClemensArth 1) That link is broken (404). 2) "*in the question itself*" means in the question itself, not a link to github.

Comment: @melpomene (https://github.com/belveder79/broken)
do you want me to copy all 4 files to the question?

Comment: Well, preferably you'd create a *minimal* example that doesn't need 4 separate files.

Comment: Perhaps the main executable and the shared library was not compiled/linked with the same settings? `-pthread` for example should be used with both.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond nope, same flags don't change anything...

Comment: `libpthread.so` is "special" ... there's a reason Musl decided to integrate it with libc. In short, *always* link to it directly from an executable. Make sure you *don't* have `--as-needed` passed to the linker, or the `-lpthread` will get removed.

Comment: @o11c you are awesome - yes, that is a nice fix

Answer (score 1):

Thx to [@o11c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405588/o11c) for pointing this out. One way to fix the problem is adding a flag to linker for the executable and explicitly add *pthread* to the list of libraries

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--no-as-needed")
target_link_libraries(test pthread dl)
```

Comment: To make your `CMakeLists.txt` portable use `find_package(Threads REQUIRED)` and link against `${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}`. Also remove `-Wl,--no-as-needed`. If you need these flags, add them manualy to CMakeCache.txt.